# Vaadin Viritin MultiSelectTable selection is not working properly

Tags: java, vaadin

I use Viritin MultiSelectTable to display JPA entities. The entities are displayed properly, but when I click on a row, all rows are selected.

I initialize my table as follows:

```
MultiSelectTable<MyEntity> acFiles = new MultiSelectTable<MyEntity>().withProperties(
        "filedate",
        "filesize",
        "rows",
        "filename"
);

acFiles.setOptions(myDAO.findAll());

acFiles.addListener(((Listener) event -> {
    System.out.println("Clicked Row");
}));
```

What am I doing wrong, so that all the rows are selected everytime I click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms sound like you have somehow badly implemented equals/hashCode method implementations in your MyEntity class and Vaadin treats all your objects the same. If it's a JPA entity a pretty well working strategy is to implement them like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if(this.id == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj instanceof MyEntity && obj.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
        return this.id.equals(((MyEntity) obj).id);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 43 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
    return hash;
}
```

The "perfect way" depends on how you use identifiers.